# Bootstrap and Stylesheet not loading Locally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following `head` section,

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

and my styles -- from both `Bootstrap` and my local stylesheet -- don't seem to be loading when I'm trying to test locally in the browsers. This happens in both `Google Chrome` and `Firefox`.

However, when I push to my `Github Pages` repository, the styles are applied and working.

**Side note**: some of the alignment styles seem to apply but none of the padding, colours etc.

Comment: Clear cached browser data, when doing web development I often have to do this to see any changes I am making.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D I've also tried running it in `Edge` and `IE` just now, both of which I'd never run it in, and the same issue applied.

Comment: are you seeing any error in the console?

Comment: @yBrodsky *sigh* Yeah, my silly self didn't think to look. The issue was `GET file:///E:/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` indicating that it doesn't seem to like my use of `/` as root? Works as just `assets/...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to load just your CSS inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

After, go to the final of the `<body>` tag and paste the other dependencies left:

```
<body>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

It will improve your system because starting with the CSS, i will not stop reading any script while loading your page.

**Edit:**

If still not working, try to remove:

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Can be a problem with external links instead.

Comment: I fixed it. Seems it didn't like the `/` before my stylesheet location like `/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css`. Removing this and having `assets/...` worked. Shouldn't either work as `/` indicates `root`? Also, any idea why this rendered fine when loading via Github?

Comment: Right. What are you using to localhost? Im using **nodejs** and couldn't simulate the problem. Everything is okay.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm simply using HTML/CSS with Bootstrap and running my local copy of `index.html` in my cloned `Github` repo via the browser.

Comment: You can use the like @ryderd said. I normally use **./**assets when it is local but it should work without the **/**.

Comment: @ryderd If I just open on my browser, it doesn't work. I local host with nodejs and work properly.

Comment: I belive it's an issue with finding the correct local `root` when using `/`. My site and its folder is nested within a few other directories on my `E:` storage drive. However, on Github Pages it can easily get the `repo root`. I find it strange because AFAIK `/` should always reconcile to the website root folder.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code seems to be the problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css">
```

Seemingly the file structure you are using locally differs from the file structure you are using on your remote repo. stylesheets.css is in the root folder in your remote repo, but it is not there in your local environment. Probably your page and stylesheets.css are in the same folder in both occurrences but the difference between the two cases is that they are in root in one case and not in root in the other case.

Comment: Hello, @Lajos Arpad!  I've mentioned it in a comment above too, but I believe you're correct. My website folder is hosted in a websites folder which is nested in another folder (and so on a few times) on my `E:` drive. So, I suspect the browser has issue finding root, whereas the repo on `Github` has a clear root.

Comment: @ryderd, I have read your comments before answering, including the one written to Katreque and based on the information I managed to find out the situation you have. This is why I have written an answer. You might want to use the very same folder structure in different versions. If my answer is correct, then you might consider accepting it, so future visitors having similar problems will be helped as well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `You might want to use the very same folder structure in different versions`?

Comment: I mean that you might have several different repos. It is quite often that people create a project, it gets successful and then they create other, similar projects which differ somehow. If you will have that situation, then you will start by cloning the initial project. You will want to use a standard folder structure to avoid confusion. You might create a staging repo to be able to test things online before deployment as well.